# Prove that $\frac{1}{\phi(D)}c=c\frac{1}{\phi(0)}$

Tags: operator-theory

Could someone prove the following?

$$\frac{1}{\phi(D)}c=c\frac{1}{\phi(0)}$$

where $D$ is ${\frac{d}{dx}}$ and $c$ is a constant.

for example $$\frac{1}{D^4+2D+3}c=c\frac{1}{0+0+3}=\frac{c}{3}$$

Comment: For certain choices of $\phi$, yes. -1 for vagueness.

Comment: Well, I guess $\phi$ does not denote the totient function...so what does it denote?

Comment: This question is way too vague to receive any meaningful answer. Please add some context and explanations

Comment: @Teri see the edit

Comment: @user130806: You want a general solution for all $\phi$? If so, then you can't have that, since there are choices of $\phi$ which make the claim false. So there's no proof because it's not true.

Comment: @mike4ty4 I already prove it for Polynomial $\phi$ but in general I cant and you said its nut true in general

Comment: You still haven't told us what $\phi$ stands for.

Comment: @KimFierens maybe I cant under stand what you mean but $\phi$ is just any function ,and this identity I saw it in my book without any prove or special case , the author wrote it and give only Polynomial example .

Comment: But how is $\phi(D)$ defined if $\phi$ is not a polynomial function? What would $\sin D$ be, for example?

Comment: @KimFierens I asked the question because I think maybe it can true in general ,can i write $\sin (D)=D-D^3/3!+..$  ?i think I cant use sin with the identity but cos yes

Comment: @KimFierens The spectral theorem allows to compute very general functions of self-adjoint operators and $-iD$ is self-adjoint in many useful context and Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. I'll be following a course in operator theory and functional analysis this semester, so maybe I'll here more about the spectral theorem and other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you should specify what class of $\phi$ you are considering or what restrictions you impose. Anyway, proceeding a bit vaguely and assuming a "nice class" (for example, at least the inverse of $\phi(D)$ and $\phi(0)$ should be defined) you can transform your equation to (multiplying by $\phi(D)$ on the left and $\phi(0)$ on the right)

$$
c \phi(0) = \phi(D) c
$$

now you can easily show that the above equation is true for, e.g. polynomials, i.e. when

$$
\phi(x) = \sum_{n=0}^N \alpha_n x^n
$$

Comment: this answer is what i need

Comment: You are welcome.